# navigatetourl not redirecting to salesforce url

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightningnavigation, forcenavigatetourl

I read a couple of documents about navigating to the page within salesforce by using "navigateToUrl".

I used this to navigate to "google.com" it is working as expected but when I'm trying to redirect to salesforce record view, it is not firing/not working. Here is the code snippet. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
var urls= 'https://customdomain.salesforce.com/' + id; // Id is record id
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                urlEvent.setParams({
                  "url": urls
                });
                urlEvent.fire();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [force:navigateToSObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToSObject/documentation) instead, this enables you to navigate to an sObject record specified by recordId.

```
createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": "00QB0000000ybNX",
      "slideDevName": "related"
    });
    navEvt.fire();
}
```